# Permission denied to new ssh user when pushing

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I'm using terminal, I want to delete ssh keys from and old user (old_username) and set a new one (new_username). I have done as is in this [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

When I run: `ssh -T git@github.com` I get the correct message:

```
`Hi new_username! You've successfully authenticated'.
```

But when I try to push a repository I get denied:

```
remote: Permission to new_username/test2.git denied to old_username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/new_username/test2/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I've tried deleting .ssh folder and setting again ssh, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Using an https url means your ssh connection is not used. At all.

Try switching to ssh:

```
git clone git@github.com:new_username/test2
```

That will actually use your ssh credentials, meaning your public and private keys stored in `~/.shh/id_rsa(.pub)`.

Answer (score 0):

If on Linux or OSX, check a file called ~/.netrc, which contains username/password information that most apps will use when connecting to remote servers. Yes, it even affects git via the https protocol. If you're using a frontend to connect to github, you probably need to clear its preferences so it stops trying to use the old username.